# Does Microsoft Word for Mac save files with extensions?

Tags: microsoft-word, file-format, file-extension, office-for-mac

When you save a document in Microsoft Word for Mac, does the resulting file have an extension (e.g. ".doc" or ".docx")?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS 9 and previous no filename extensions where used, and I believe that MS Word did not use them either. Mac OS X uses filename extensions, and so does MS Word.